# Android: create a ContextMenu by Buttonclick or Edittext

Tags: android, contextmenu, android-context

I have a Button/Edittext to reset my App-Settings....

If a press the button(no long click), I want to get a Contextmenu with a Button where i can confirm the reset or not!

Which listener do i need for my Button to call a ContextMenu?

Is a also possible to create a contextmenu by this method?

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        //create Contextmenu to confirm or not
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

and how can i get a Textview or a Button in a ContextMenu() ?!?
 Do u have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can actually start the `ContextMenu` on a `Button` click(this menu could be handled directly by the Android system).

You should use a `Dialog`(or `AlertDialog`) to get your user choice.